# How do I put timer on session destroy codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, model-view-controller

How can I put a timer on my `$this->session->sess_destroy()` from my model without using the `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;` on config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it expires 7200 i think. and from what I know, dynamically setting it doesn't work. Why do you want it anyway? Maybe we can suggest, but the answer would be you can't.

http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-31039.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this

**//set session expire time, after that user should login again**

```
$this->session->sess_expiration = '1800'; //30 Minutes
$this->session->sess_expire_on_close = 'true';
```